# Rijndael algorithm goes wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, stream, cryptography

I found this one article: [link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx)

What I'm trying to do: encrypt Byte() array and then decrypt it.
It works but the result of decrypting is not equal to origin array.
Mine code:

```
Dim RMCrypto As New RijndaelManaged()
RMCrypto.Key = Key
RMCrypto.IV = IV
RMCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros

Dim dataToDecrypt As Byte() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}

Dim encrypted As Byte() = Encrypt(dataToDecrypt, RMCrypto)
Dim roundtrip As Byte() = Decrypt(encrypted, RMCrypto)
```

Where

```
Private Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As Byte(), RMCrypto As RijndaelManaged) As Byte()

Dim encrypted() As Byte
Using RMCrypto
    ' Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(RMCrypto.Key, RMCrypto.IV)
    ' Create the streams used for encryption.
    Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
        Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)

                'Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
            End Using
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

    ' Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    Return encrypted

End Function 'Encrypt
```

And

```
Private Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText() As Byte, RMCrypto As RijndaelManaged) As Byte()
Dim plaintext As Byte()

Using RMCrypto 

' Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(RMCrypto.Key, RMCrypto.IV)

' Create the streams used for decryption.
    Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(cipherText)
        Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
            Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                ' and place them in a string.
                plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srDecrypt.ReadToEnd())
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

Return plaintext

End Function 'Decrypt
```

How it works:

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
encrypted: 221 54 108 65 95 233 31 124 101 181 205 176 13 233 85 252
decrypted: 15 45 15 239 191 189 239 191 189 14 58 239 191 189 9 118 37 239 191 189 212 149 239 191 189 58
```

As we can see it looks like encryption is right, but decryption is totally wrong - it even have another number of members!

P.S. can it be in due to incorrect converting from string to Byte() in `Decrypt` function?
One more interesting moment: `decrypted` change it's size and give a new answer every time!

Comment: Rijndael is a block cipher, and in the default (CBC) mode it produces/expects ciphertext in blocks of 128 bits = 16 bytes. Your `dataToDecrypt` is only 11 bytes long, and is therefore not a full block and so cannot be decrypted.

Comment: @Iridium you are right! I changed it's size to 16 bytes and got another error. Can you take a look at this one?

Comment: Try changing to different values of [**`rijAlg.Padding`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding(v=vs.110).aspx), it could fix the problem Iridium describes.

Comment: @Iridium I totally rephrase my question. I hope now it's clear! Can you look at it again?

Comment: @VisualVincent Hi, Vincent! Looks like using `Padding` fix all my problems, but now I can't figure out my decrypted and origin arrays are so different. I edited my question can you take a look at it, please?

Comment: You are still reading from the memory stream before closing the stream during decryption. Furthermore, you are *encoding* the data as UTF-8 instead of leaving the bytes alone. The input plaintext for Encrypt already seems to be specified as bytes, so logically the output for Decrypt should also be bytes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, didn't get issue about MemoryStream... Can you talk about it in details? I put data to MemoryStream and then read it. Maybe it read more bytes than needed and what is why decrypted result is wrong?
I tried to avoid `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` but it told me that `srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()` must be String! Why If I put Byte() to it? Looks like `ReadToEnd` method works in this way...

Comment: You need to let the CryptoStream's using end before reading the contents out of the memorystream.

Comment: @bartonjs I still can't figure out this. I tried to `REadBlock` then and limit how much data to read. But then I took error `The offset and length have exceeded the bounds of the array or the counter value exceeds the number of elements from the pointer to the end of the original collection.` Can you give me an advise or example?

Comment: `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()` during encryption should be behind the `End Using` of the `CryptoStream`. The reading during decryption is likely OK. But don't convert to UTF-8 there, you just need bytes as returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, really there's a whole lot wrong with your code.

My code snippets are going to be in C# because I haven't written VB in over 15 years. While they can read similarly I don't want to end up giving invalid syntax.

#### 1) You Dispose your object via a `using`, then use it again.

Apparently for `RijndaelManaged` this just puts it back in the "I've never been used state", which causes the next use to generate a random key and IV.  This was probably your biggest problem.

So, your Encrypt and Decrypt methods should remove the `using` statements for the symmetric algorithm object (currently named `RMCrypto`).  Usually the creator of an object owns the lifetime, sometimes the lifetime is handed off to new objects; but almost never is the lifetime supposed to be terminated by a method you call.

#### 2) You're using RijndaelManaged.  Don't.

You want AES (a restricted form of Rijndael, but one that interoperates much better).  You "could" switch to `AesManaged`, but shouldn't.  Instead, you should use `Aes.Create()` (some of the Aes-derived types only work on specific (versions of specific) operating systems.  `Aes.Create()` is supposed to always work.

#### 3) You're reading from the MemoryStream before the CryptoStream finishes.

Your call to `msEncrypt.ToArray()` is inside the CryptoStream's `using`, but you want it to be outside.  Flip those two lines.

#### 4) You're using PaddingMode.Zeros.

While this might be what you want, it probably isn't.  AES (and Rijndael) is a block cipher algorithm, and block ciphers require complete blocks to operate.  When the last block is deficient it gets "[padded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Byte_padding)" to completion.  PKCS7 is the "standard" padding mode, and the decryption can remove it (because it has strong enough rules). ANSI X.923 and ISO 10126 can also both be removed during decryption.  Zeros cannot, because the "unpadder" can't tell if the zeros were real zeros, or padding zeros.

#### 5) You named your variable `dataToDecrypt`.

You're passing it to Encrypt, then the output of Encrypt to Decrypt.  So this is just `data`.

#### 6) You applied a UTF-8 decode in Decrypt.

Your text is bytes from 1 to 16, that's definitely not UTF-8 text.

The StreamReader/StreamWriter you use suggest that you were trying to perform encryption on strings.  Don't.  Encryption/decryption is on bytes.  (Aside from novelties like the Caesar cipher).

### All told:

```
// The using goes here, with the Create call. Not in anything it gets passed to.
using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;
    // PKCS7 is the default padding mode,
    // if you don't like trusting defaults you can set it here.

    byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

    byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(data, aes);
    byte[] roundtrip = Decrypt(encrypted, aes);
}

private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, SymmetricAlgorithm alg)
{
    // You didn't have a using for this, but should have:
    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = alg.CreateEncryptor())
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        // Now that the CryptoStream has closed the data has been padded.
        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, SymmetricAlgorithm alg)
{
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = alg.CreateDecryptor())
    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Just keep using this in write mode. All it does is say whether
        // You'll be explicitly loading data via Write, or implicitly via Read.
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csDecrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        // Now that the CryptoStream has closed the data has been de-padded.
        return msDecrypt.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bartonjs, that is awesome answer! Thank you very much, I got a lot of information! Now the `using` problem is clear for me. I will try `aes` instead of `Rijndael` but here is important what method was used to encrypt data in 3d party application (as I told my task is only decrypt data). I thought a lot about padding, I know about block structure of the cipher, as I understand they use zero padding for this and additional number for useful number of bytes in data.
Great clarification about getting Byte instead String - my code was based on example I found in net, so I used it :(

Comment: One more comment: I suppose here is a typo in your code: in decrypt function must be `using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = alg.CreateDecryptor())` instead of `using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = alg.CreateEncryptor())`

Comment: Bartonjs, I rewrite it in VB.net, works perfectly! Thank you. I have one more question about algorithm: when encrypt <16 bytes I get 16-bytes encrypted. But if I try to encrypt 16 bytes I will get 32-bytes encrypted. The problem: I have 128-byte, but cannot encrypt it because for correct decrypting I need 128+16 bytes. Can you help or It is better to create new question?

Comment: If you have a "correct answer" you're trying to attain then perhaps you do want PaddingMode.Zeros. If that doesn't help, or you'd like to know more, that'd be better as a different question (which probably already exists, but I couldn't find it offhand).

Comment: Yep! `PaddingMode.Zeros` works perfectly! The last one question: I decrypt a lot of data step by step. Would it be more effective to declare Aes in global and do not create it every time I get data?

Comment: Within reason. If you're going to do 100 operations with the same algorithm and padding mode (and perhaps key) then holding an instance and carving off 100 calls to CreateEncryptor is reasonable, but since you should always use a new IV for encryption call GenerateIV() between them.  But for a long-running process you'd dispose it out once you're going back to idle.